# Converter uma consulta sqlalchemy em um dicionário - Python

Tags: banco-de-dados, python-3.x, string, dicionário, sqlalchemy

Eu tenho esta consulta feita com `SQLalchemy ORM`, onde `table_schema` contém um exemplo de coluna sqlalchemy

```
nq = session.query(Base.table_schema).filter(Base.tablename == 'stores').scalar()
```

O resultado me retorna isso:

```
'{"id": Column("id", INTEGER(), table=<None>, primary_key=True, nullable=False, server_default=DefaultClause(<sqlalchemy.sql.elements.TextClause object at 0x07F7B190>, for_update=False)), "nk_store": Column("nk_store", VARCHAR(length=40), table=<None>), "store_code": Column("store_code", VARCHAR(length=40), table=<None>), "store_level": Column("store_level", VARCHAR(length=40), table=<None>), "ownership": Column("ownership", VARCHAR(length=40), table=<None>), "ownership_label": Column("ownership_label", VARCHAR(length=40), table=<None>),  "store_supplier": Column("store_supplier", VARCHAR(length=40), table=<None>),"n1_supplier": Column("n1_supplier", VARCHAR(length=40), table=<None>), "n2_supplier": Column("n2_supplier", VARCHAR(length=40), table=<None>), "status": Column("status", VARCHAR(length=40), table=<None>), "__tablename__": "stores"}'
```

Quero transformar essa consulta (que é uma string) em um `dict`, assim:

```
{"id": Column("id", INTEGER(), table=<None>, primary_key=True, nullable=False, server_default=DefaultClause(<sqlalchemy.sql.elements.TextClause object at 0x07F7B190>, for_update=False)),
 "nk_store": Column("nk_store", VARCHAR(length=40), table=<None>),
 "store_code": Column("store_code", VARCHAR(length=40), table=<None>),
 "store_level": Column("store_level", VARCHAR(length=40), table=<None>),
 "ownership": Column("ownership", VARCHAR(length=40), table=<None>),
 "ownership_label": Column("ownership_label", VARCHAR(length=40), table=<None>),
 "store_supplier": Column("store_supplier", VARCHAR(length=40), table=<None>),
 "n1_supplier": Column("n1_supplier", VARCHAR(length=40), table=<None>),
 "n2_supplier": Column("n2_supplier", VARCHAR(length=40), table=<None>),
 "status": Column("status", VARCHAR(length=40), table=<None>),
 "__tablename__": "stores"}
```

Tento usar `json_dumps`, mas não funciona, então tento `ast`, mas tenho este erro:

```
import ast

result = ast.literal_eval(nq)
assert type(result) is dict

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Acho que esse erro acontece porque quando o python tenta transformar nq em um `dict`, ele não reconhece os valores como uma string, mas ainda não tenho certeza. Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Se você está utilizando o flask você pode usar o marshal para fazer a serialização do seu query result em um schema que você preferir, caso não esteja usando flask você pode usar dataclass ou o proprio pydantic.

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

observando a documentação do sqlalchemy há uma método que retorno o conteúdo deste KeyedTuple como um dicionário.

Método **_asdict()**: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple._asdict

[Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958219/convert-sqlalchemy-row-object-to-python-dict) tem um exemplo de como utilizar.